# Magento 1 - How to trigger the password reset email to customer , instead of an email with an auto-generated password?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, password, forgot-password

Magento 1 - How to trigger the password reset email to customer , instead of an email with an auto-generated password ?

Answer (score 0):

Here we are trying to (trigger/send) the password reset email to customer. 
Instead an email with an auto-generated password.

We can achieve this functionality by following the steps below :-
We will create a checkbox field (Send forgot password email) in customer information section
same as "send autogenerated password" and when CS
checks that box and saves the customer information
we will be using "adminhtml_customer_save_before" event
that triggers on customer save before from customer information section backend
"doBeforeSave()" method is listening on this event
here we will get the (customer id , email) , we will check field "Send forgot password email" checkbox value if its set then we will use this code
ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920153/create-and-send-email-to-customer-reset-password-link-programmatically-in-magent,
to send the reset password link email to the customer.